# Can you call the main function at the top in python like perl?

Tags: python, perl

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

For example this perl code works, but python does not?

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl5.18
main();

sub main {
    print 'hello\n';
    return;
}
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4
main()

def main():
    print('hello')
    return
```

Thanks

Comment: main is undefined until you hit the def line, in python you have to define the function before you call it

Comment: if you import it from other module/file, yes you can :) that's a joke, btw. 
python reads code from top to the end. in any case if interpreter finds a usage (evaluation, execution) of an undefined variable, function etc. it stops working with an error code. have a look up this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985047/order-of-execution-and-style-of-coding-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write definition of `main` before you call it:

```
def main():
    print('hello')
    return

if __name__ == "__main__": # Avoid running main function when this file is imported instead of run directly.
    main()
```

Comment: Re "You need to write definition of main before you call it", No, calls can precede definitions.

Comment: @ikegami You can write codes that call it before definitions, but you can't run those codes and really call the function before the function is assigned to its codes.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try:

```
def main():
    print('hello')
```

and then call it as main()

Comment: The OP is asking how to call it before you have it defined which is not possible

Comment: @ikegami, you can, you just have to make sure the functions are defined before you call one, once it is defined it is globals so accessible from anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a call to a function before the function is declared, except if the call is within another function. Workaround:

```
def top():
    main()

...

def main():
    print('hello')
    return

top()
```

Not sure why you'd want to do that. In either language. It's definitely error-prone in Perl.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can use the function only after defining it earlier.