# External dictionary reading behavior in a class

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have found this behavior that I can not understand. I state that this is a simplification of the problem I'm having, since the dictionary in my script has a lot more items.

```
configuration = {
    "video": {
        "fullscreen": {
            "user": None,
            "default": False
        }
    }
}

class test():

    fullscreen = configuration["video"]["fullscreen"]["user"]

    def __init__(self):
        print(configuration)
        print(configuration["video"]["fullscreen"]["user"])
        print(self.fullscreen)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    configuration["video"]["fullscreen"]["user"] = True
    t = test()
```

This is the result:

```
{'video': {'fullscreen': {'user': True, 'default': False}}}
True
None
```

Why in the third print the result is "None"?

Comment: You assigned an object to a class attribute which happened to be a value in the dict. You then change that reference in the dictionary. You never touch the attribute again, so of course, it stays the same.

Comment: In short, the third print prints `None` because you assigned `None` to the attribute you are printing, and never changed it after that, so of course it will still be `None`. Note, the fact that it is a class attribute is irrelevant. This would work the sam way if you had just assigned to a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the explanations given so far to your question were not really totally clarifying to me the order of instructions execution in your more-than-legitimate question. I think I perfectly understood what you meant and it puzzled me too

The following example will show you that the class attribute `user_conf` [renamed to avoid focusing on the wrong point] is created before running `configuration["video"]["fullscreen"]["user"] = "John"` in the `main()`. In other words - at pure class attribute level - its value is set from the `configuration` blueprint. It will be only the class constructor - called after the `main` - to update that value later

```
configuration = {
    "video": {
        "fullscreen": {
            "user": None,
            "default": False
        }
    }
}
# correcting global variable blueprint
# configuration["video"]["fullscreen"]["user"] = "John"

class test():

    print(configuration["video"]["fullscreen"]["user"])
    user_conf = configuration["video"]["fullscreen"]["user"]
    print(user_conf)

    def __init__(self):
        # printing modified global variable, all right
        print(configuration)
        print(configuration["video"]["fullscreen"]["user"])
        print(self.user_conf)
        self.user_conf = "Jack"
        print(self.user_conf)

def main():
    # modifying global variable later
    # at this point the class attribute user_conf has already been assigned with the old value
    configuration["video"]["fullscreen"]["user"] = "John"
    test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please notice that if you comment the value update in the main and uncomment these lines that I added:

```
# correcting global variable blueprint
# configuration["video"]["fullscreen"]["user"] = "John"
```

just after the configuration declaration you will have the output without any `None` that you were expecting to find, because the class attribute will be created by a "corrected" blueprint. In this case then you will get:

> John 
> John 
> {'video': {'fullscreen': {'user': 'John', 'default':
> False}}}
> John
> John
> Jack

Another way to produce this tweaking the sample at point 6 [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables):

```
def outer():

    configuration = {
      "video": {
          "fullscreen": {
              "user": None,
              "default": False
              }
          }
    }  
    print("initial outer configuration:", configuration)
    
    def inner():
        nonlocal configuration
        '''
        configuration = {
          "video": {
              "fullscreen": {
                  "user": "John",
                  "default": False
                  }
              }
        }  
        '''
        configuration["video"]["fullscreen"]["user"] = "John"
        print("inner configuration:", configuration)
    
    inner()
    print("modified outer configuration:", configuration)

outer()
```

which would give:

> initial outer configuration: {'video': {'fullscreen': {'user': None,
> 'default': False}}} 
>  inner configuration: {'video':
> {'fullscreen': {'user': 'John', 'default': False}}} 
>  modified
> outer configuration: {'video': {'fullscreen': {'user': 'John',
> 'default': False}}}

Hope this can solve better your doubt

---

**Edit after the OP comment**: as I openly declared it took me some time to figure out what is happening. Let's take this code:

```
configuration = {
    "video": {
        "fullscreen": {
            "user": None,
            "default": False
        }
    }
}

print("step 1 -> " + str(configuration))

# correcting global variable blueprint
# configuration["video"]["fullscreen"]["user"] = "John"

class test():

    print("step 2 -> " + str(configuration))
    user_conf = configuration["video"]["fullscreen"]["user"]

    def __init__(self):
        # printing modified global variable, all right
        print("step 5 -> constructor reads the updated value: " + str(configuration))

def main():
    # modifying global variable later
    # at this point the class attribute user_conf has already been assigned with the old value
    print("step 3 -> " + str(configuration))
    configuration["video"]["fullscreen"]["user"] = "John"
    print("step 4 -> main just updated the global variable: " + str(configuration))
    test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Printing this will give you the following output:

> step 1 -> {'video': {'fullscreen': {'user': None, 'default': False}}}
>
>  step 2 -> {'video': {'fullscreen': {'user': None, 'default':
> False}}} 
>  step 3 -> {'video': {'fullscreen': {'user': None,
> 'default': False}}} 
>  step 4 -> main just updated the global
> variable: {'video': {'fullscreen': {'user': 'John', 'default':
> False}}} 
>  step 5 -> constructor reads the updated value:
> {'video': {'fullscreen': {'user': 'John', 'default': False}}}

Now, if you read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2985085/4092588) you will easily understand that Python is executed top to bottom and executing a `def` block - in our case `__init__(self)` - doesn't immediately execute the contained code. Instead it creates a function object with the given name in the current scope which is actually entered only after calling `test()` from `main()`, i.e. only after you ask to instance an object from the `test()` class, which will trigger its constructor

**IMPORTANT**: in your case I realized that you are calling the class `test()` and `test()` is what you are calling from `main()`. Your main is calling a method actually, `test()`: so please replace `class test()` with `def test()` in the previous code and you will get a different and more understandable execution flow:

> step 1 -> {'video': {'fullscreen': {'user': None, 'default': False}}}
>
>  step 3 -> {'video': {'fullscreen': {'user': None, 'default':
> False}}} 
>  step 4 -> main just updated the global variable:
> {'video': {'fullscreen': {'user': 'John', 'default': False}}} 
> step 2 -> {'video': {'fullscreen': {'user': 'John', 'default':
> False}}}

After the first `print` all the def blocks are skipped and we enter the `main()`. The `main()` updates the global variable and then the `test()` function would work immediately on the updated value. Of course the constructor in this case would not be triggered [this is not anymore a class] and this explains the lack of step 5

**-> are you sure you are making a good choice in defining and using your class in this way?** [probably not] 
**-> isn't it better to declare `test()` as `def` instead that as `class`?** [I really think so]

Comment: Thank you for your complete and complete answer. A doubt in reality there is still me. The fact that in my example I posted, changes occur before calling the class. So once I copy the value in the dictionary with an internal variable, why not copy the value change? I do not know if I explained myself correctly.

Comment: @BlackFenix06 I modified the content trying to explain better some steps and making you think about the way you implemented the code. Check it out and let me know. As of now I will leave all the things I wrote so far, after I may trim to make it shorter. Have a good day

Comment: The problem is that the test I put. It's a test and that's it. in the real code I have several classes, the first one that is executed is the one that loads the data from a file and places them in the configuration variable. Then move on to the main class that uses that data ...

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour occurs because `self.fullscreen` refers to the class attribute which is defined before the edit to the one in the global scope.

Once you create it, it goes into the class’ `__dict__` so changing the one in the outer scope obviously will have no correlation to the on stored in the class.

*I have a feeling you’d get different results if you had written `fullscreen = configuration` since it may refer to the same dictionary object.*